# Tightening Manfrotto Ball Head

Tags: tripod, tripod-heads, ball-head

I have  [Manfotto Compact Ball Head](http://www.manfrotto.com/product/8374.31708.22608.0.0/486RC2/_/Compact_Ball_Head_With_RC2_Plate(200Pl-14)-_Holds_13.2lbs.) that I love but it is getting to the point to where I can't tighten it enough to keep my camera steady.

When I tighten it, the joints of the tripod interfere with the lever, preventing me from really locking it down so the camera can't move.  Is there any way to adjust the position of the lever so that the locked position is different?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Their site suggests that you can pull the lever outwards so that you can clear obstructions. Have you tried that?

Comment: Having almost the same ballhead (different QR plate), I know it works. Pull the lever outwards, turn it and let go. Then tighten from there, repeat as needed.